# what is the row id equivalent in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, netezza

In our legacy DWH process, we find duplicates and track that duplicate records based on rowid in traditional RDBMS.

For ex.

```
select pkey_columns, max(rowdid) from table group by pkey_columns
```

will return only the duplicate records corresponding max records. Even when we identify the duplicate records, this helps in identifying/tracking the record.

Is there an equivalent in pySpark ? How is this handled in dwh to pyspark dwh translation projects ?

Comment: PySpark Dataframes are non-indexed, distributed datastructures. They do not have row-id's. If you can explain your question better with what you want and what you have tried, we can still help you

Comment: if your intention is to remove duplicates then you can use 
df1 = sqlContext
     .createDataFrame(rdd1, ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4'])
     .dropDuplicates()

Comment: thanks for the response.
what i need is to track a record using a rowid (--> like md5).
Im understanding there is no direct answer to this, but what is the alternative. I would like to save the current dwh model/remodelling efforts. 

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the analytic function library, perhaps a

```
ROW_NUMBER()
OVER( PARTITION BY group pkey_columns 
    ORDER BY sort columns)
```